# MySQL: apply a GROUP BY query to an entire table

Tags: mysql, group-by

i have a table `tbl_cross` contains the field `number` and the field `register_id` that is a foreign key to another table `tbl_registers` that contains the primary key `id` and a foreign key `collection_id`.

With the following query I get duplicates number for register 1050.

```
SELECT qt.*
FROM 
(
    SELECT cr.number, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
    FROM tbl_cross AS cr
    WHERE cr.register_id = 1050 
    GROUP BY cr.number
) AS qt
WHERE qt.cnt > 1 
ORDER BY qt.number ASC
```

and the result is for example:

```
number | cnt
    11 |   2
   181 |   3
   252 |   2
```

Pretty simple. Now, I would to know how to go JOIN with the table `tbl_registers` to get every duplicate for each register.

```
register_id | number | cnt
       1050 |     11 |   2
       1050 |    181 |   3
       1050 |    252 |   2
       2023 |     12 |   2
       3034 |     77 |   3
       3034 |    106 |   2
```

Or adding a WHERE condition to get duplicates value for each register belongs to collection 56 (`collection_id=56`), for example.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Join the two tables and group by both columns.

```
SELECT cr.register_id, cr.number, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM tbl_cross AS cr
JOIN tbl_register as r ON cr.register_id = r.id
WHERE r.collection_id = 56
GROUP BY register_id, number
HAVING cnt > 1
```

You can use `HAVING` to filter out the non-duplicates, you don't need a subquery.

Comment: Your query is basically ok, just fix tbl_register to tbl_registers, but the problem is we need the condition cnt > 1, because we want olny duplicates! So cnt >= 2 and we need a SELECT of a SELECT. However thansk

Comment: Oh, I was thinking `cnt > 0`!

Comment: HAVING perform better than a SELECT of a SELECT?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're after is something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        reg.id,
        reg.collection_id,
        cr.number,
        COUNT(*) AS ct
    FROM tbl_registers AS reg
    INNER JOIN tbl_cross AS cr
        ON cr.register_id = reg.id
    GROUP BY
        reg.id,
        reg.collection_id,
        cr.number
) duplicates
WHERE duplicates.ct > 1
-- AND duplicates.collection_id = 56
```

Comment: I think it's better to have the condition collection_id=56 inside, not outside. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're directly asking about a GROUP BY statment. You want your register_id grouped so you dont have duplicates, but also so you can still see the number of each registeredId.

Tech on the net is a fantastic reference for all your SQL questions have a look: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php

All the best and welcome to Stackoverflow!!